# React - useState - update state: value vs function

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I was wondering if there is any difference between passing a value and passing a function to update state in a functional component when referencing a previous state, as in below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);

  const increaseCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  const increaseCounter2 = () => {
    setCounter2(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={increaseCounter}>
        Increase
      </button>
      <h1>Another Counter: {counter2}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={increaseCounter2}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The official documentation mentions this in the functional updates section:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Yet here, it uses a different method:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd presume that it does not matter which way in a very basic example as above but there'll probably be cases where one is necessary/preferable to the other.

EDIT: just to clarify my only question is about the difference (when to use) between:

```
setCounter2(prevState => prevState + 1);
```

and

```
setCounter(count + 1);
```

I understand that in both cases in a real example, it (ie. setCounter) should ideally be taken to a separate function (not coded inline in jsx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE:

`setCounter2(prevState => prevState + 1);`
and

`setCounter(count + 1);`

there is a differences but depending on use case. The way you have used in example there is no difference. But

```
// Example 1
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(count + 1)
}, [count])

// Example 2
useEffect(() => {
  setCounter2(prevState => prevState + 1)
}, [])
```

in example 1: useEffect has a dependency requirement which is count.
in example 2: useEffect dont have any dependency requirement reason prevState is a call back.

when to apply

1. If useEffect only depends on count change then example 1 should apply
2. if useEffect has other dependencies but you dont want to trigger useEffect on count change then example 2 should apply

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(someOtherThingsChanged) {
    setCounter2(prevState => prevState + 1)
  }
  
}, [someOtherThingsChanged])
```

You can read more in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: Sorry, either I'm completely missing the point of your post or you're not exactly answering the question I'd asked:)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense